# Error compiling angular universal on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, angular, ubuntu, server-side-rendering

At the time of executing `npm run build:ssr --prod` stays at 16% and shows me the following error

`16% building 54/56 modules 2 active ...d-optimizer/webpack-loader.js??ref--7-0!/home/fepr/project/node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/core.jsKilled npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 137 npm ERR! project@0.0.0 build:ssr: ng build --prod && ng run project:server:production npm ERR! Exit status 137 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the pelisencasa@0.0.0 build:ssr script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!     /home/fepr/.npm/_logs/2021-01-26T00_10_33_005Z-debug.log` 
in local it manages to compile but not in the server

I don't know what I'm failing guys any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running code with sudo command?

Comment: Hello friend, I already solved it, for whoever this is happening, the solution is to increase memory to the server, it was not able to compile it ran out of resources